# rails csv import ram consumption issue postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, memory-leaks

I have implemented the CSV import in my rails app. Now the issue is ram consumption is too high. The total no. of records in my CSV is around 3600 and my ram consumption is going around 600MB - 800MB and it doesn't even get flushed after coming out of the import method.

I can see similar issue in roo issue list https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/issues/179

I am working on
Rails 4.2.6
Ruby 2.2.4

code:

```
data = CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true)

data.each do |row|

    Model.create(row ....)

    .........

end
```

Initially my ram consumption is:

```
GetProcessMem:0x7fd3083b2a30 @mb=204.52734375
```

Before getting out of the method:

```
GetProcessMem:0x7fd30ae1a7a0 @mb=289.60546875
```

After completing and redirecting to home page:

```
GetProcessMem:0x7fd2fb3913d8 @mb=629.61328125
```

With this much ram consumption, I cannot deploy it on heroku.
This consumed ram doesn't even gets cleaned up, have to restart my server for it.

Anyone up with a solution or any alternative way to import csv.

Comment: I think you're just doing it wrong try this link to see a comparison of all methods. Last two in particular. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this gem [smarter_csv](https://rubygems.org/gems/smarter_csv) and use the batching process. This will cut the import into groups and **lower the amount of ram needed** for the operation.

*Ex. in 500 row groups*

```
    SmarterCSV.process(file, {chunk_size: 500 }) do |array|
      array.each do |sub_array|
        if User.find_by_order_id(sub_array[:order_id]).present?
          User.update_attribute :shipping_id, sub_array[:order_id]
        end
      end
    end
```